# Youtube Analytics API filters not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I am trying to retrieve viewerPercentage based on gender, ageGroup filtering by country.

```
'ids' => 'channel=='.$channel->channel_id,
'start-date' => $monthAgo,
'end-date' => date("Y-m-d"),
'metrics' => 'viewerPercentage',
'dimensions' => 'ageGroup,gender',
'filter' => 'country=='.$country->code,
'access_token' => $tokens->access_token
```

The problem is that for each country it retrieves the same data. Therefore, for 50+ countries it gives the same data, which I don't think it is possible.
What I am doing wrong? Thank you


**SOLVED**
`'filter'` changed to `'filters'`